# C++ template specialization for enum

Tags: c++, templates

I want to map known type to enum value defined by myself.

```
enum class MyType : uint8_t {
    Int8,
    Uint8,
    Int16,
    Uint16,
    Int32,
    Uint32,
    ... // some other primitive types.
};

template <typename T>
constexpr uint8_t DeclTypeTrait();

template <>
constexpr uint8_t DeclTypeTrait<int8_t>() {
  return static_cast<uint8_t>(MyType::Int8);
}
... // Specialize for each known number type.
```

Also for any enum type defined by user, I want to map it to Int32. User must define his enum class on int32_t.

```
using Enumeration = int32_t;

// Some user defined enum.
enum class CameraKind : Enumeration { 
    Perspective, 
    Orthographic 
};
```

So I implement DeclTypeTrait like this:

```
template <typename T,
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
constexpr uint8_t DeclTypeTrait() {
  return static_cast<uint8_t>(MyType::Int32);
}
```

But I got error: "call to 'DeclTypeTrait' is ambiguous"

```
candidate function [with T = CameraKind]
candidate function [with T = CameraKind, $1 = void]
```

My question is how to accomplish this:

```
// If a have a variable of known types or any enum on int32.
int8_t v1;
CameraKind camera;
std::string s;

DeclTypeTrait<decltype(v1)>() -> MyType::Int8
DeclTypeTrait<decltype(camera)>() -> MyType::Int32
DeclTypeTrait<decltype(s)>() // Report compile error is OK.
```

Comment: Can you use C++20? concept makes things easier.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I can only use C++17.

Comment: You have two overloaded functions, one of them with a specialization. This complicates things. You should use a class template instead, which would allow partial specializations. Also you probably shouldn't limit the underlying type of user enums. Use `std::underlying_type_t` to inspect the underlying type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class template will be much simpler for your case.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct DeclTypeTraitT {
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr uint8_t DeclTypeTrait = DeclTypeTraitT<T>::value;

template <>
struct DeclTypeTraitT<int8_t> {
    static constexpr uint8_t value = static_cast<uint8_t>(MyType::Int8);
};

template <typename T>
struct DeclTypeTraitT<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>> {
    static constexpr uint8_t value = static_cast<uint8_t>(MyType::Int32);
};
```

Then

```cpp
CameraKind camera;
static_assert(DeclTypeTrait<decltype(camera)> == static_cast<uint8_t>(MyType::Int32));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qM6axK4Gn)

---

As @HolyBlackCat saying, if you want to map the underlying type, you can use

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct DeclTypeTraitT<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>> {
    static constexpr uint8_t value = DeclTypeTrait<std::underlying_type_t<T>>;
};
```